# Ajax call is not passing parameter to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the Controller I added a method to perform some live data exchange into a div.

```
public class TextItemsController : Controller
{

    //[HttpPost]       
    public JsonResult SpinText(string Body)
    {
        SpinningResult spinningResult = new SpinningResult();

        spinningResult.Spintext = "This is the result text";

        string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(spinningResult);

        return Json(jsonResult);
    }
}
```

This works in general and the result is sent back to the calling Ajax method and the div is updated with the result text as intended. So the general communication seems to work. But I never receive the input string from the Ajax call.

```js
function doSpinning() {
    //var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', $('#textForm')).val();
    var myData = { Body : "Hello" };    
    //var dataWithAntiforgeryToken = $.extend(myData, { '__RequestVerificationToken': token });
    var requestData = JSON.stringify(myData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/TextItems/SpinText",
        type: "POST",        
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: requestData,
        success: function (data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = json["Spintext"];              
        },
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = "Error";    
        }
    });
}

$("#spinButton").on('click', doSpinning);
```

`data` seems to have the correct value `"{"Body":"Hello"}"` before the post but `string Body` is always `null`.

Comment: You are posting an *object* with a property called `Body`, not a parameter called `Body`. You should either post the text unmodified with a text content type or change the action parameter to an object

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to prefix your parameter with [FromBody] like this :

```
public JsonResult SpinText([FromBody] DtoBody Body)
```

And use a data transfer object so the JsonSerializer will know how to map the sent data

```
public class DtoBody 
{ 
   public string Body {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting an `object` with a `Body` property, and your method expects a `string` value. These don't match up, obviously, but you don't need to post an object when you only want to pass in a primitive:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/TextItems/SpinText",
    type: "POST",        
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "Hello",
    success: function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = json["Spintext"];              
    },
    error: function () {
        document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = "Error";    
    }
});
```

---

Note that this is not your only problem though, as you are doing a double JSON serialization on your Action:

```
// serialize to JSON
string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(spinningResult);

//serialize the serialized object
return Json(jsonResult);
```

You never have to explicitly serialize to JSON, that's what the helper does for you.

Just use:

```
public IActionResult SpinText(string Body)
{
    SpinningResult spinningResult = new SpinningResult();
    spinningResult.Spintext = "This is the result text";

    return Json(spinningResult);
}
```

And, again, you don't need to double-parse the JSON on the AJAX result:

```
success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = data.spintext;              
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I got it with a mix of your help.

**DTO**

```
public class SpinningInput
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult SpinText([FromBody]SpinningInput spinningInput)
{
    SpinningResult spinningResult = new SpinningResult();
    spinningResult = Utility.Spinning.SpinText(spinningInput);

    return Json(spinningResult);
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
function doSpinning() {
    const textBody = document.getElementById("Body").value;
    const textTitle = document.getElementById("Title").value;
    const textTags = document.getElementById("Tags").value;
    const textKeyword = document.getElementById("Keyword").value;
    var textData = { Title: textTitle, Body: textBody, Tags: textTags, Keyword: textKeyword };    
    var requestData = JSON.stringify(textData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/TextItems/SpinText",
        type: "POST",        
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: requestData,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = data.spintext;     
            document.getElementById("WordCount").innerHTML = data.wordCount;
            document.getElementById("KeywordDensity").innerHTML = data.keywordDensity + "%";
        },
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = "Error";    
        }
    });
}

$("#spinButton").on('click', doSpinning);
```